# I want to extract text values from text in spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, information-extraction, named-entity-recognition

I am new in using spacy. I want to extract text values from sentences

```
training_sentence="I want to add a text field having name as new data"
        OR
training_sentence=" add a field and label it as advance data"
```

So from the above sentence, I want to extract "new data" and "advance data"

For now, I am able to extract entities like "add", "field" and "label" using Custom NER.

But I am unable to extract text values as these value can be anything and I am not sure how to extract it using custom NER in spacy.

I have seen code snippet [here](https://spacy.io/usage/examples#entity-relations) of **entity relations** in the spacy documentation
But don't know to implement it as per my use case.

I can't share the code. Please assist how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that framing this as a pure named entity recognition problem really makes sense here. Named entities are usually proper nouns and "real world objects" – for example, a person name like "John Doe", an organization name like "Google", or things like diseases or genes, to name examples from a more specific domain. This is also what spaCy's named entity recognizer is optimised for.

In your example, it seems like most of the clues are actually in the **syntax**, which is something you can usually predict pretty well out-of-the-box. For instance, you're looking for verbs like "add" and "label", and their objects ("text field") or attached prepositional phrases. If you visualize the syntax, e.g. using the `displacy` module, you'll see that there's a lot of relevant information in the sentence structure that you can extract programmatically:

```py
from spacy import displacy
doc = nlp("I want to add a text field having name as new data")
displacy.serve(doc)
```

[image: Visualization of sentence]

You can also use the [rule-based matcher](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-matching) to find trigger tokens like `"label"` (with the part-of-speech tag `VERB`) and then check the [dependency tree](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-dependency-parse) to find the tokens attached to them. For example, if the verb "label" is attached to a preposition "as", you can be pretty sure that the *object* attached to it is the name of the label. Or you could start at the root of a sentence and iterate over its [`subtree`](https://spacy.io/api/token#subtree) and check whether it contains tokens or constructions you're interested in.

You might have to experiment a little and you'll probably end up with a bunch of different rules to cover different types of constructions that are common in your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @InesMontani. I want to know how can I create multi rule-based matcher. So that I can able to **extract values** even if the sentence can be in any sequence like: `sentence1="I want to add field having name datadata" OR sentence1="Add field having name datadata" OR sentence1="User need field and label it datadata" ` and how can it detect multiple verbs like `sentence2="I need to add field datata and remove field notsomuchdata OR sentence2="Just remove field datadata and user require a field specificdata"`